# Using Pandas to Convert from Excel to CSV and I Have Multiple Possible Excel Sheet Names

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am trying to convert a large number of Excel documents to CSV using Python, and the sheet I am converting from each document can either be called "Pivot", "PVT", "pivot", or "pvt". The way I am doing some right now seems to be working, but I was wondering if there was any quicker way as this takes a long time to go through my Excel files. Is there a way I can accomplish the same thing all in `one pd.read_excel` line using an OR operator to specify multiple variations of the sheet name?

```
for f in glob.glob("../Test/Drawsheet*.xlsx"):
    try:
        data_xlsx = pd.read_excel(f, 'PVT', index_col=None)
    except:
        try:
            data_xlsx = pd.read_excel(f, 'pvt', index_col=None)
        except:
            try:
                data_xlsx = pd.read_excel(f, 'pivot', index_col=None)
            except:
                try:
                    data_xlsx = pd.read_excel(f, 'Pivot', index_col=None)
                except:
                    continue
    data_xlsx.to_csv('csvfile' + str(counter) + '.csv', encoding='utf-8')
    counter += 1
```

Comment: I afraid there is no other quicker way to this as you are not certain about the file name. if there would have been any other way using OR operator as you asked that would also need to go through each possibility once to see which is correct and raising error(obviously, there is no way out to this) for others and would end up consuming almost the same amount of time

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't so much about find the correct special syntax for `pd.read_excel` but rather knowing which sheet to read from. Pandas has an `ExcelFile` that encapsulates and some basic info about an Excel file. The class has a `sheet_names` property that tell you what sheets are in the file. (Unfortunately documnetation on this class is a bit hard to find so I can't give you a link)

```
valid_sheet_names = ['PVT', 'pvt', 'pivot', 'Pivot']

for f in glob.iglob('../Test/Drawsheet*.xlsx'):
    file = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    sheet_name = None

    for name in file.sheet_names:
        if name in valid_sheet_names:
            sheet_name = name
            break

    if sheet_name is None:
        continue

    data_xlsx = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name, index_col=None)
    ...
```

However, this is not strictly equivalent to your code as it does not do 2 things:

- Cascade `read_excel` if the chosen sheet fails to be loaded into a data frame
- Have a priority ranking for the sheet names (like `PVT` first, then `pvt`, then `pivot`, etc.)

I'll leave you on how to handle these two problems as your program requires.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks so much! After I've compiled all of these into one file, do you know how it would be possible to go line by line and only keep certain rows? For example, I have four columns, and only want to keep rows where the fourth column says "Expired" while I want to get rid of rows where the fourth column is blank.

Comment: That's basic filtering: `df = df[df['FourthColumn'] == 'Expired']`